# Getting OSError: [WinError 6] The handle is invalid while working on os module

Tags: python, python-3.x

I an new-bee to python and seek help for below error.
I am using Jetbrains pycharm
C:\Users\mayur>python --version
Python 3.8.0

code I am having:

```
    import os
    tw=os.get_terminal_size()
    print(tw)
```

error I am getting, please assist for this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/mayur/PycharmProjects/Python/practise_test_working_with_strings.py", line 2, in <module>
    tw=os.get_terminal_size()
OSError: [WinError 6] The handle is invalid
```

If I run the same code using command line , it is working fine:

````
```
>>> import os
>>> tw=os.get_terminal_size()
>>> print(tw)
os.terminal_size(columns=120, lines=30)
```
````

Comment: If your intention is to get the terminal size(and not run the exact code you have posted), you can try using `shutil.get_terminal_size` instead of `os.get_terminal_size`.

Comment: Thanks Shiva for the update. My intention is to get the columns size to print some text at the middle of terminal:
os.get_terminal_size().columns    print(my_str.center(tw))

Comment: Can you try using `shutil.get_terminal_size` instead of `os.get_terminal_size`?

Comment: The OP's code used to work for me, but stopped working. So, I searched, found this question & thought that I would note that `shutil.get_terminal_size().columns` works for me